# How to handle pagination with IMobileServiceSyncTable and Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, pagination, azure-mobile-services

How do you paginate data returning from the `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>.PullAsync()` method?

I've tried doing something like this, but it's not working how I expected:

`myTable` is a `IMobileServiceTable<T>`

`mySyncTable` is a `IMobileServiceSyncTable<T>`

```
// Already tracking how many records exist
// Note* Not using the sync table here, because that was not getting the correct results. 
// It seemed more correct to use the regular table so it was "live" data.
var totalCount = myTable.Take(0).IncludeTotalCount().ToListAsync();

// Try and sync a "page" of data, limited by the values here
var query = mySyncTable.Skip(count).Take(maxPerPage);
await mySyncTable.PullAsync(null, query);

// At this point, I expect the local store to have a set of data
// So I try and get that "page" of data
var results = await mySyncTable.ReadAsync(query);

// That returns 0 results, so I tried
var results = await mySyncTable.Skip(count).Take(maxPerPage).ToEnumerableAsync();

// Still 0 results, so just give me all the things
var results = await mySyncTable.ToEnumerableAsync();

// Still 0...
```

I am getting `totalCount` greater than 0, but when I think I am reading from the local store, I can't seem to get results back with Skip and Take. Please suggest how to properly paginate data from a sync table.

Answer (score 3):

To start, you can't share the skip portion of a query (or even take) between server & client since the data sets will be different.

A pull query that syncs 10 records (skipping 10, take 10, say pulling record 10-20), will result in the local table having 10 records (assuming it had none to start)  Running a skip 10, take 10 there, would result in 0 records being found locally.

Otherwise the actual code to page should be ok in general for getting record X-Z.  Although you may want to be explicit on sort order (orderby X) since depending on config of Azure SQL & MySQL the default orders may not align .

Now there does appear to be some issue occuring, as the second ReadAsync, is also returing no results.  Unfortunately it could be a number of things.

First I'd output the result value of the PullAsync, it could be failing for expected reasons (data couldn't be pushed, connection to server failing, etc)

If that looks ok, the next best bet is to enable a tool like Fiddler to see what is happening over the wire.  Is the client properly making a call to /tablename?$skip=X&Take=Y, and the server returning a 200 with the results you'd expect?

Usually those steps show the most common causes, if that all checks out, the next step would probably be to confirm the synctable API writes & reads fine to the table (maybe an issue in teh table define call, or sql setup, etc locally)

Comment: You make an excellent point in your first sentence. I will have to double-check that this is not an issue in my scenario. I was starting at 0-10 on both, and while that is prone to the issue you mention, my scenario does not match the indexes getting out of sync. 

I do have a decent amount of logging / error handling, especially in my SyncHandler and that did not appear to be the issue. I will investigate further on your other suggestions and report back. Thanks for your time.

Comment: So that it does not go to total waste, I will award the bounty here because this answer involves the sync table, and offers some advice on how to investigate further - hopefully leading to the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The following document indicates how to do paging: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/#paging

Short version:

```
// Define a filtered query that skips the top 3 items and returns the next 3 items.
MobileServiceTableQuery<TodoItem> query = todoTable
                .Skip(3)
                .Take(3);
List<TodoItem> items = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Azure Mobile Apps has a default 50-row limit on returns.  To override the 50 row limit in a Mobile App backend, you must also apply the EnableQueryAttribute to the public GET method and specify the paging behavior. When applied to the method, the following sets the maximum returned rows to 1000:

```
[EnableQuery(MaxTop=1000)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found those docs, and that's where I got my basic implementation. However, that's not specifically for a "SyncTable", which is where my confusion is coming in. If I don't use a SyncTable, and instead just use a IMobileServiceTable, it works as expected. The issue is using a sync table, and paging the sync / local read.